# what mean this strange httpError?

Tags: ajax, http, jsf, jsf-2, xmlhttprequest

I use JSF in implementation MyFaces 2.0
I have 2 jsf pages login.xhtml and register.xhtml.

login.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

 <h:head>
     <title>System CollDoc</title>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
    <h:form>
       <h:panelGrid columns="3" >
             <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Login:"/>
             <h:inputText id="username" value="#{userManager.userName}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.requiredLoginMsg}">
                  <f:ajax event="blur" render="usernameMessage"/>
             </h:inputText>
             <h:message id="usernameMessage" for="username" />

             <h:outputLabel for="password" value="#{msg.password}"/>
             <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{userManager.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.requiredPassMsg}">
                  <f:ajax event="blur" render="passwordMessage" />
             </h:inputSecret>
             <h:message id="passwordMessage" for="password" />

             <h:commandButton value="#{msg.login}" action="#{userManager.login}"/>
       </h:panelGrid>
     </h:form>

     <h:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true"/>

     <h:link value="#{msg.register}" outcome="register.xhtml"/>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

register.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

 <h:head>
     <title>System CollDoc</title>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
    <h:form>
       <h:panelGrid columns="3" >
          <h:outputLabel for="login" value="Login:"/>
          <h:inputText id="login" value="#{registerBacking.registerLog}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.requiredLoginMsg}">
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="usernameMessage"/>
       </h:inputText>
       <h:message id="usernameMessage" for="login"/>

       <h:outputLabel for="pass" value="#{msg.password}"/>
       <h:inputSecret id="pass" value="#{registerBacking.registerPass}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.requiredPassMsg}">
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="passwordMessage" />
       </h:inputSecret>
       <h:message id="passwordMessage" for="pass" />

       <h:commandButton value="#{msg.login}" action="#{registerBacking.register}"/>

     </h:panelGrid> 
   </h:form>

   <h:link class="link" value="#{msg.returnTxt}" outcome="/pages/login.xhtml"/>

 </h:body>
</html>
```

I run my application and first i see `login.xhtml` page. I click at first inputText "username" and next at inputSecret "password" (validation for "username" is run by ajax request on blur), next at link to register page (validation for "password" is run by ajax request on blur) and i get dialog with error:

```
Error Message: Request failed with status 0 and reason 

--------------------------------------------------------
Calling function:myfaces._impl.xhrCore._AjaxRequest
Error Name: httpError
--------------------------------------------------------
Note, this message is only sent, because project stage is development and no other error listeners are registered.
```

I click "ok" button and i get register.xhtml page in my web browser. At register page situation is same: I click at inputText "login", next at inputSecret "pass" (validation for "login" is run by ajax request on blur) next i click link back to login page or button to run business logic (validation for "pass" is run by ajax request on blur) and i get same error

What does error mean? What is wrong?

---

**Edit:**

I run my application again now and i don't get any error message. Why do I get this error only sometimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a result of mixing AJAX and 'regular' requests. When the button is hit two requests run in parallel: one - AJAX request for validation on blur, and second - form submit of commandButton.
JSF detects it when AJAX request is completed and reports it as a potential problem (e.g. if both requests did some actions on server side which were inter-dependent).

Probably simplest way to fix it in your case is to make the button do AJAX request as well (add `f:ajax` to the `h:commandButton`), then JSF will put the request to the queue what will guarantee that requests are made serially but not concurrently.

Comment: why do I get this error only sometimes? I run my application again now and i don't get any error message

Comment: As the two requests run in parallel, sometimes one completes fast enough that JSF does not notice that something was running in parallel (e.g. if the ajax request completes before second request is sent - for jsf it will look like the requests are done serially).